# making filled dropdown values readonly

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I tried making dropdown readonly if the data exists in database. But when even if i make it readonly, user can change the values i mean dropdown values. so i changed it to disabled. but in this, i cannot receive the values after submission. Here is my code

```
<select name="sign" <?php echo empty($row['sign']) ? '' : 'readonly' ?> class="form-control">
        <option value="<?php echo $row['sign']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sign']; ?></option>
        <?php $m1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM signs");
        while($m2 = mysqli_fetch_array($m1)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $m2['sign']; ?>"><?php echo $m2['sign']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Any code on the client side could be manipulated. If you would like to keep it from being edited, then I highly recommend that you do this on the server. Do not trust the client for anything.

Comment: you mean to say, i should check it while submitting to database?

Comment: Yes. I highly recommend that and it is said to be "good practice"

Comment: @McStuffins: Thanks. I will do that only.

Comment: Alright. No problem. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is this `<?php echo empty($row['sign']) ? '' : 'readonly' ?>`
maybe u can do this `<?php echo (empty($row['sign']) ? '' : 'readonly'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is when you make it disabled, to add another hidden input with the same name and value.

Other solution is to prevent user from changing the select, there are many javascript options, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qk2Pc/

HTML:

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
my_condition = true;
var lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");

$("#my_select").change(function(){
  if(my_condition)
  {
    lastSel.attr("selected", true);
  }
});

$("#my_select").click(function(){
    lastSel = $("#my_select option:selected");
});
```

Comment: The reason why Stack didn't let you use the URL here is that it requires the code for it also. So please add that the next time you suggest a jsfiddle; I won't always be here ;-) (I just added that for you).

Comment: @Nikolay Ganovski: i am submitting data to database through a page called submit.php. where i should mention it then?

Comment: I assume your <select> is inside a form. Just after the </select>, add <input type='hidden' name='sign' value=''<?php echo $row['sign']; ?>" > . Thus in case you use 'disabled' for your select.

Comment: I cant do that, as there are 4 dropdown, if other dropdown lists doesn't have db value, then also it takes hidden values instead of user entered values, right?

Comment: yes, you have to write your "if" conditions for every select